# How do I save individual species data downloaded via rgbif?

Tags: r, csv

I have a list of species and I want to download occurrence data from them using rgbif. I'm trying out the code with just two species with the assumption that when I get it to work for two getting it to work for the actual (and much longer) list won't be a problem. Here's the code I'm using:

```
#Start
library(rgbif)
splist <- c('Acer platanoides','Acer pseudoplatanus')
keys <- sapply(splist, function(x) name_suggest(x)$key[1], USE.NAMES=FALSE)
OS1=occ_search(taxonKey=keys, fields=c('name','key','decimalLatitude','decimalLongitude','country','basisOfRecord','coordinateAccuracy','elevation','elevationAccuracy','year','month','day'), minimal=FALSE,limit=10, return='data')
OS1
#End
```

This bit works almost perfectly. I get data for both species divided by species. One species is missing some columns, but I'm assuming for now that's an issue with the data, not the code. The next line I tried -

```
write.csv(OS1, "os1.csv")
```

works fine when saving a single species but not for more than one. Can someone please help?  How do I save data for each species as separate files, bearing in mind I also want the method to work for data for more than 2 species?

Thanks!

Comment: I see your question has been answered below. I'm the main author of `rgbif`, if you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a list, which means you can use R's functions to climb each list element and save it. The following code extracts species names (you might have this laying around somewhere already) and uses `mapply` to pair species data and file name and use this to save a `.txt` file.

```
filenames <- paste(sapply(sapply(OS1, FUN = "[[", "name", simplify = FALSE), unique), ".txt", sep = "")

mapply(OS1, filenames, FUN = function(x, y) write.table(x, file = y, row.names = FALSE))
```

This is akin to a `for` loop solution, but some might argue a more concise one.

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  write.table(OS1[[i]], file = filenames[i], row.names = FALSE)
}
```